# Running two monitors on two different nVidia cards

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 16.04, multiple-monitors

I have two different nVidia cards. I'm using a GTX750 as my primary cards and it's connected to a 1600x900 screen. The other card, Geforce G210 is connected to another screen, but the screen stays blank. How could I get them to work?

The cards:

> `lspci| grep Ge
>   01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107 [GeForce GTX750] (rev a2)
>   06:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218 [GeForce G210] (rev a2)`

<s>It seems, that I've managed to install separate drivers for the two cards, using the addition drivers tab in settings, but the other screen is still blank.</s>
Ignore that, after a second reboot, my whole linux crashed. I had to uninstall all nVidia drivers and reinstall the ones for my GTX750. So I got nowhere.

Output from xrandr | grep conn:

> DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left
>   inverted right x axis y axis) DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left
>   inverted right x axis y axis) HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left
>   inverted right x axis y axis) HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left
>   inverted right x axis y axis) DVI-D-0 connected primary 1600x900+0+0
>   (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 443mm x 249mm

So it's not detecting the other card. Also xrandr --listproviders has only one provider:

> Providers: number : 1
>
> Provider 0: id: 0x1b9 cap: 0x1, Source Output crtcs: 4 outputs: 5 associated providers: 0 name:NVIDIA-0

Comment: Can someone even confirm if it's possible or not? I've searched all over the internet, but noone seems to be able to help me.